# Canvas requestAnimationFrame bug on window refocus

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm doing some animation work in canvas and have just implemented time-based animation.

I'm getting a weird bug that's only occurring occasionally. When I switch tab, so the window loses focus, upon switching back to the tab the animation is in there is a 'lag' for a couple of frames.

Replicating this is proving to be quite hard, as it happens after leaving the window for some arbitrary amount of time, but this is not consistent i.e. i've left it for 5,10,30 minutes and upon refocusing the window the bug does not occur.

Here's the culprit:

```
lastTime = Date.now();

function gameLoop(){

    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    var thisTime = Date.now();
    var deltaTime = (thisTime - lastTime);


    if(deltaTime > 160){ //If deltaTime is above 160 (roughly 6fps) 
                            //it's assumed the user switched tab

        deltaTime = 0;
    }
    lastTime = thisTime; //Update lastTime
    draw();
    update(deltaTime * timeMultiplier);


}
```

I'm assuming the bug is in the if condition, this is in place because without it the deltaTime variable keeps incrementing until the window is refocused. I think the problem is in the 1000/60 assignment with the nature of it being a literal... due to the nature of requestAnimationFrame I don't know what value to put in place there.

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, requestAnimationFrame (RAF) is designed to halt running when you its browser tab loses focus.

When its browser tab regains focus, the animation resumes.  A small lag may occur because RAF takes a small bit of time to resume.  At 60fps the delay could be as much as several frames.

*Your deltaTime will not be calculated when RAF is halted*

When RAF is halted, your gameLoop is not executed and your deltaTime is not incrementing--therefore your "if" is not triggered.

When RAF resumes Date.now() is much larger than lastTime, so your "if" will most likely be triggered immediately.

If you **want** an operation to keep running while the tab is out of focus, use setTimeout or setInterval.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want the gameLoop to stop executing when the browser loses focus. Is there any work-around to stop that lag? My objective here is simply to make the animation independent of hardware, is that the effect of the above code? I'm from an XNA background where gametime is implementing for you so i'm new to implementing it myself.

Comment: I edited my function btw, as the previous if was actually being executed every frame. That alert is actually being triggered twice upon refocusing the tab, which seems weird

Comment: RAF will always stop when the browser tab loses focus--it's designed that way.  Your "if" alert will trigger immediately upon RAF restarting because your Data.now() is based on the system clock and has certainly run off more than 1 second since losing focus.   Since it takes you more than 1 second to click-close the alert box, your second alert box is firing.  To clarify: Do you want your animation to keep running when the tab loses focus? If so, use setInterval or setTimeout instead of RAF.

Comment: Oh of course, I didn't take into account for the clicking of the alert box! Just shows the value of experience :P. No, now I understand it is working as intended thanks to your explanation. I want the animation to stop when the tab loses focus. Thanks!